# Can Javascript send href without being clicked?

Tags: javascript, click

I wan to send value with this href without being clicked.

```
<a href="javascript:getSearch('funny')">Funny</a>
```

Is there any  method to attain  this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Call the function directly `getSearch('funny')` from JS

Comment: To Tushar, would you plz code it for me? I'm just a novice.

Comment: This is not how SO works! You should try it, when you face any issues ask a question.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    getSearch('strawbale');
});
</script>
</div>    .... Is it right?

Comment: What does "send href" mean?  And, if you don't want it to happen on a click, what event do you want it to happen on?

Comment: Just do <script> getSearch('funny'); </script> somewhere below declaration of function. And google JS onload event if function is defined in external file (and it looks like someone is trying to trigger some ads xss)

Comment: To  BozidarS, <script> getSearch('funny'); </script>? Does it worK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jquery for it here is a working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/35anxyps/)

Here is code

Html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="abc" data-value="funny">Funny</a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var a = $('#abc').data('value');
    alert (a);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer